# LibreOffice - convert Calc/Excel schedule to CSV from command line

Tags: command-line, csv, conversion, libreoffice

I'm trying to batch convert some Excel schedules to CSV format
from the command line with the following LibreOffice command:

```
libreoffice --convert-to csv *.xlsx
```

I'm getting:

```
error
xsltParseStylesheetFile : cannot parse 
I/O warning : failed to load external entity ""
error
xsltParseStylesheetFile : cannot parse 
convert file.xlsx -> file.csv using filter : Text - txt - csv (StarCalc)
```

I'm actually getting a csv file like this, but I also get a GUI-message saying "the maximum number of columns per sheet was exceeded." 
Also I am getting lots of `���`
for unsupported German characters `ä ü ö`. 
Does anyone know how to fix those errors?

---

**Update:**

running: `libreoffice --convert-to "txt:Text (encoded):UTF8" File.xlsx`

I get:

> Warning loading document File.xlsx: 
> The data could not be loaded completely because the maximum number
> of columns per sheet was exceeded.
>
> ---
>
> OK

<sup>[manually transcribed from [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpeul.png)]</sup>

and on the command-line:

```
convert /home/user/File.xlsx -> /home/user/File.txt using filter : Text (encoded):UTF8
Error: Please verify input parameters... (SfxBaseModel::impl_store <file:///home/user/File.txt> failed: 0xc10(Error Area:Io Class:Write Code:16) /build/libreoffice-RsXkGA/libreoffice-7.0.1~rc1/sfx2/source/doc/sfxbasemodel.cxx:3153 /build/libreoffice-RsXkGA/libreoffice-7.0.1~rc1/sfx2/source/doc/sfxbasemodel.cxx:1735)
```

Might that be because of the Excel `xlsx` format?

Comment: Looking through the `--help` I found this line `--convert-to "txt:Text (encoded):UTF8" *.doc`  Maybe it's possible to specify charset for CSV?  No idea what "out of range" implies here, are there any other errors in the actual CSV?

Comment: @OskarSkog thanks for the answer, I updated my Question: "out of range" was a bad translation from German language. I changed the tty to english and made a screenshot :-)

Comment: Looks like it is a really big spreadsheet, too big to fit in the available columns in LibreOffice Calc, can you confirm this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Are you obliged to use libreoffice?***

A great command-line tool to convert xlsx to csv is [xlsx2csv](https://bioinf.shenwei.me/csvtk/usage/#xlsx2csv)

> **Description:** convert xlsx files to csv format  xlsx files are zip
> archives where spreadsheet data is stored. In  order to process a
> file, various bits inside the archive need to be  located. This
> utility uses the Expat SAX parser to collect the strings  into a
> simple dictionary, keyed by their relative position in the XML  file.
> This makes it possible to process files of any size.

**Installation on a Debian-System:**

```
sudo apt install xlsx2c
```

**Simple usage:**

```
xlsx2csv infile.xlsx outfile.csv
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply and much thanks! Really great tool! No errors, very simple usage and plain output. No ��� forl `ÄÖÜäöü…`